# yum-builddep building the dependencies from source

Tags: rhel, yum, rpmbuild

My current way of building packages from srpm:

- `cd ~/rpmbuild/SRPMS`
- `yumdownloader --source $p`
- `sudo yum-builddep *.src.rpm`
- if some build deps not found, repeat the above steps for each of them
- `rpmbuild --rebuild *.src.rpm`
- `sudo yum --nogpgcheck install ../RPMS/*/*.rpm`
- if some install deps not found, repeat the above steps for each of them

There is still too much manual work. I need some better tool, which can:

- resolve srpm name more reliably. `yumdownloader` can't always guess it:

  ```
  [git@dioptase SRPMS]$ yumdownloader --source pdf-tools
  Enabling rhel-source repository
  Enabling epel-source repository
  No Match for argument pdf-tools
  Nothing to download
  ```

  ( In this case `pdf-tools-0.29a-2.1.el6.noarch.rpm` is built along with `perl-Text-PDF` )
- Automatically build and install from source the dependencies missing in the repos (both build and install deps).
- Maybe create `repodata/` in `RPMS/*/` , so I won't need to deal with rpm filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I think you are tying to solve a human problem programmatically, which is not yet ready to be solved so, you may want to look into the mock builder tool.  I'm told it can assess dependencies and install those as required.

Comment: yes, switched to mock as soon as I learned about its existence

Comment: FYI, we switched from using mock to using docker and our builds are enormously faster.